# Extracting data from XML file: count and sum are zero

Tags: python, xml

I am writing a program in Python that will prompt for a URL, read the XML data from that URL using urllib and then parse and extract the comment counts from the XML data, compute the sum of the numbers in the file. Here is the code:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?'
sum = 0

while True:    
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
    print data
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)

    lst = tree.findall('comments/comment')
    print lst
    print 'Count: ', len(lst)

    for item in lst:
        num = int(item.find('count').text)
        sum = sum + num

    print sum
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter location: http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml
Retrieving http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=http%3A%2F%2Fpython-data.dr-chuck.net%2Fcomments_42.xml
Retrieved 107 characters
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
</GeocodeResponse>

[]
Count:  0
0
```

I don't understand why the list is empty, which leads to a count and sum of zero. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Even I am stuck at the same point. Did you get the answer by now or still struggling? If yes, please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're downloading [this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=http%3A%2F%2Fpython-data.dr-chuck.net%2Fcomments_42.xml), which has no comments snippets... so the list is empty because you can't find them.
Try with:

```
url = urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
```

instead as a test.
Basically it is just a problem with the url you entered.